# how to pass two parameters in api to update data?

Tags: angular, mongodb, command-line-interface

I am sending two values orderid and status, according to orderid i want to update status but status is coming as undefined.

```
this.httpClient.put(`/api/updateOrder?orderId=${reqId}`,status="done")
 .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

```
__api.updateOrder = function(req, status){
collection.update({orderId:"req.query.orderId"}, {$set:{status: "req.query.status"}}),(function(err,results){
if(err){
 console.log(err);
}else{
console.log('updated successfully');
}
}
```

I expect that status should be updated to done.

Comment: /api/updateOrder?orderId=${reqId}&status=done`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way to pass query params.

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('status', 'done');
this.httpClient.put(`/api/updateOrder?orderId=${reqId}`, params);
```